# Non-violent misbehaviors in California, 2014

Tags: data-request, usa, education

Where can I find the stats for the NON-VIOLENT MISBEHAVIORS were referred to on January 8, 2014 by U.S. Secretary of Education Arne Duncan, citing California’s data?

> “nearly half of the more than 700,000 suspensions statewide in the 2011-12 school year were for, quote, ‘willful defiance’”.
>
> “Nationwide,” he noted, “as many as 95 percent of out-of-school suspensions are for nonviolent misbehavior--like being disruptive, acting disrespectfully, tardiness, profanity, and dress code violations”.

[Rethinking School Discipline, Arne Duncan, 2014](http://www.ed.gov/news/speeches/rethinking-school-discipline).

Answer (score 1):

I added the URL above, which is the transcript of the speech you are referencing: [Rethinking School Discipline](http://www.ed.gov/news/speeches/rethinking-school-discipline). I was thinking the data would come from the later-mentioned [Office of Civil Rights - Data Collection](http://ocrdata.ed.gov/), which turns out to have some [cool data resources](http://ocrdata.ed.gov/flex/Reports.aspx?type=school) for entire US (demographics, students with disabilities, etc).

But I think this 700k number comes from the [CA Dept. of Education - Expulsion and Suspension site](http://www.cde.ca.gov/ds/sd/sd/filesesd.asp). There you'll find 3 TXT files with data from the last 3 school years. The structure of the files is [explained here](http://www.cde.ca.gov/ds/sd/sd/fsesd.asp).

*Willful defiance* is defined ([source](http://www.sfgate.com/bayarea/article/Oakland-to-halt-school-suspensions-for-willful-6262461.php))

> a broad category of misbehavior that includes minor offenses such as refusing to take a hat off or ignoring teacher requests to stop texting and more severe incidents like swearing at a teacher or storming out of class.

So from the above data, you can construct "willful defiance" suspensions as the "total suspensions" minus the "violent suspensions" in a given year.